# How to avoid collision of enumerated values?

Tags: c

I'm building a front-end library. The back-end produces a number of error codes that are enumerated:

```
enum backerr {BACK_ERR1, BACK_ERR2, BACK_ERR3};
```

My front-end produces a number of additional error codes:

```
enum fronterr {FRONT_ERR1, FRONT_ERR2, FRONT_ERR3};
```

For convenience I would like to have a single error code returning function that would return both front end or back end errors depending on which one occurred.

Is there any way this can happen without collision of the values of two error codes, and considering we cannot know the values of the back-end?

Comment: I've tackled this before.  I think the front-end has to know enough about the error codes of the backend make sure the front-end error codes are a superset of the back-end codes.  You might try reserving the first 1000 numbers for the back end and use the rest for the front.

Comment: Another option is for the error code to have some part that indicates which enum it's from, and the rest that indicates the enum value

Comment: By far the simplest mechanism is to define that all backend errors are negative and all frontend errors are positive, or vice versa, and reserve 0 for 'not an error'. Consider how you might handle system errors (`errno` values in the range 1 to roughly 150 can appear in either frontend or backend); you might want to keep at least 1..200 reserved for the O/S, with positive and negative value to distinguish between frontend and backend as before. I worked on software that used error numbers between 100 and 121 for its own errors; it was fine when `errno` only went to 50, but gave endless grief.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have access over the back-end. My front-end is a separate project. And all the specification of the back-end says is that the error codes should be non-zero so I guess it might differ among implementations. I might be asking too much.

Comment: If you can't control the backend, you can't control these enumerations.  You'll have to devise a mechanism that reliably tags the source of the error as frontend or backend, and accept that you may well end up with the same error number meaning two different problems, depending on whether the source is frontend or backend.  The other problem comes later when the ecosystem evolves and what was frontend becomes part of the middle, and there's new frontend codes, and so on.  You may need a tagging system that handles more than just the frontend/backend dichotomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *know* what the back end may generate then, no, there is no way to reliably select your own error codes so that they don't clash.

So you have a couple of options (at least).

The first is useful if the back end somehow publishes the error ranges, such as in a header file. To be honest, it *should* be doing this since there's no other way for a *program* to distinguish the different error codes and/or types.

If they *are* published, it's a simple matter for you to discover the highest and select your own codes to leave plenty of room for the back end to expand. For example, if the back end uses `1..100`, you start yours at `1000`. The chance of any system suddenly reporting ten times as many errors as the previous version is a slim one.

A second way is if you want real separation with zero possibility of conflict.

There's nothing to stop you returning a structure similar to:

```
struct sFrontError {
    enum fronterr errorCode;
    enum backerr  backendCode;
};
```

and using that for your errors. Then your enumeration for the front end becomes:

```
enum fronterr {FRONT_OK, FRONT_BACK, FRONT_ERR1, FRONT_ERR2, FRONT_ERR3};
```

and you can evaluate it as follows:

- If `errorCode` is `FRONT_OK`, there is *no* error.
- If `errorCode` is `FRONT_BACK`, the error came from the back end, and you can find its code in `backendCode`.
- Otherwise, it's a front end error and the code in `errorCode` fully specifies it.

Comment: A similar option is to use a scheme like [HRESULT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT).

Comment: Good additional approach.  Is there any reason you have declared `errorCode` and `backendCode` as `int` and not as the respective `enum`s?  I know it's allowed in C but find it a bit confusing.  Another source for inspiration might be the C++ [`system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error) header that attempts to solve a similar problem (except that it additionally needs to support *multiple* backends) in a similar manner to the solution you are showing.

Answer (score 1):

If the backend exposes an exhaustive list of its error codes you can easily create a true superset of them with your own frontend error codes being a disjoint subset.

```
/* in backend.h */

enum backend_error
{
  BACK_ERR_1,
  BACK_ERR_2,
  BACK_ERR_3,
};
```

```
/* in frontend.h */

#include <backend.h>

enum frontend_error
{
  FRONT_ERR_1 = BACK_ERR_1,
  FRONT_ERR_2 = BACK_ERR_2,
  FRONT_ERR_3 = BACK_ERR_3,
  FRONT_ERR_4,
  FRONT_ERR_5,
};
```

This method doesn't force you to make any assumptions on the values of the backend error codes but if a future version of the backend defines additional error codes, you might be hosed.  Another downside is that your header file `#include`s the backend's header so you are polluting the namespace.

If your users never call into the backend directly, that is, you are providing abstractions for all backend functionality, you can define your own error codes altogether and have a function that maps backend error codes to your own.  Since it is not required for this function to be the identity function, you can always make this work even in face of future changes to the backend.  It can also be implemented in your own implementation file to keep the backend namespace out of your user's picture.